# pointer won't go back to it's reference from a function after return (stays null) C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return

im using my own linked list made with stuct. The struct has 2 ints and 1 pointer to another struct, next.

I'm using the LL (linked list) but in one of the functions a certain pointer won't change.

```
AddChain( &MakeChain(..values..), added )
```

this is how i call the function, i send her a new chain to link to the big one, and if there is no big one aka it's NULL so it will replace it. In this call added is a NULL ptr to a chain struct.

```
void AddChain(PolyChain* pol, PolyChain* main) // adds the new piece to the chain
{
    PolyChain *current = main, *back = NULL;

    if (main == NULL)
    {
        pol->next = NULL;
        main = pol;
        return;
    }
... \\ there is continuation of the function but it wont get so far without main one
}
```

Now, as you can see if the main chain is a NULL I make to to reference to the same thing as the new chain I got. I'm running in the debugger and pol **HAS** a value and after the line:

```
main = pol;
```

main realy changes to point to what pol is pointing to. BUT after the return in AddChain, **added** which is the *main* in AddChain is still a NULL. It didn't get the value back from the function, it didn't change the pointer of added as like it was by value and not by reference, but it was by reference.

What's causing this problem?

EDIT: MakeChain returns a PolyChain and AddChain gets PolyChain*, this is why i used &.

Comment: You pass your pointer by value. Think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use pointer to pointer to modify pointer value inside the function

```
void AddChain(PolyChain* pol, PolyChain** main)
```

than in your code:

```
void AddChain(PolyChain* pol, PolyChain** main) // adds the new piece to the chain
{
    PolyChain *current = *main, *back = NULL;

    if (main == NULL)
    {
        pol->next = NULL;
        *main = pol;
        return;
    }
... \\ there is continuation of the function but it wont get so far without main one
}
```

to pass value to the function just call

```
AddChain(pol, &main);
```

where `pol` and `main` are regular pointers to `PolyChain` type.

or with simple values:

```
PolyChain* pMain = &main;
AddChain(&pol, &pMain);
```

**NOTE: This practics are extremaly error prone so you must be extra careful for managing pointers at this manner.**

Comment: I have a problem with regular types, when I try to pass PolyChain with &(&L))

Comment: @Ofek .T. What did compiller says?

Comment: with &(&) it says - expression must be an lvalue or a function designator

Comment: @Ofek .T.  Did you try the last one example?

Comment: Of coure address of pointer (&*) would work but that will force to make a pointer every time I want to use the function just to send it, and then recieve it, the variable will mean nothing to me and it's just extra work in the code usage

Comment: @Ofek .T.  What can i say its the pay for usage pointer to pointer. Its not much work. Its designed for working with pointers not with variables.

Comment: Yes I know, but i wanted to find a way which is easier in the code. Thanks, ill use the ** method and create pointers.

Comment: @Ofek .T. Glad can help you!) Good luck!)

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you pass your pointer `PolyChain* main` by value. A simple way of visualizing "passing by value" is to think about it as "passing by copy": a copy of the pointer is made specifically for the call of `AddChain`. That is why any change to the pointer inside `AddChain` remains local to `AddChain`.

You could fix this problem in three different ways:

- **Take `PolyChain*& main` by *reference*** - this is the simplest solution. because nothing else needs to change.
- **Take `PolyChain** main` by *pointer*** - in this case `AddChain` needs to dererefence `main`, i.e. use `*main` instead of `main`, and take a pointer when passing `main` to `AddChain`
- **Return `PolyChain*` with the new value of `main`** - in this case the caller must make an assignment of the result back to the pointer passed for `main`.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing a copy of the pointer, since you are passing the pointer by value. If you want to change the pointer that comes from the calling scope you will have to pass a pointer to the pointer or a reference to the pointer:

```
void AddChain(PolyChain*& pol, PolyChain*& main) {...}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
void AddChain(PolyChain* pol, PolyChain* main)
...
        main = pol;
        return;
```

In that code, `main` is a local copy of whatever pointer was passed in, so assigning to `main` has no effect on the pointer outside the function.

You didn't give enough information for me to deduce your intent, so it is likely (but not clear) that you could fix the problem by passing the pointer by reference:

```
void AddChain(PolyChain* pol, PolyChain*& main)
```

Comment: But if I do so, how do I pass a PolyChain to the function? With PolyChain* I would just do &variable_name, but now this doesn't fit

Comment: @Ofek .T.  In the same manner. `AddChain(&pol, &main)` where `pol` and `main` are variables of `PolyChain` type.

Comment: It doesnt. PolyChain l = MakeChain(2, 2, NULL);
 AddChain(&MakeChain(1, 4, NULL), &l); give me error saying that it's not correct

Comment: @Ofek .T.  Did you try to do, what i posted belove? It certainly must work.

Comment: @Ofek .T.  I also noticed than your make chain function return a value. Where did you store it?

Comment: @Ofek .T.  You in this case must return a pointer with dynamicaly allocated memory

Comment: The question showed the call as `AddChain( &MakeChain(..values..), added )` and wanted `added` to be changed by that call.  If you make the code change I suggested (to the signature line of `AddChain`) that will work.  **NO** change is required to that call.